# how do I solve this 400 firebase flutter error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm having issues connecting the firebase server to flutter, I'm following all the steps from youtube video, but when trying to run the main.dart I'm receiving this error:

'400 Bad Request trying to find package cloud_firest ore at https://pub.dartlang.org.'
I don't know what to do at this point, I'm pretty new to flutter.
Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: cloud_firest ore vs cloud_firestore

Comment: There's no package named `cloud_firest ` in https://pub.dartlang.org/, you should use `cloud_firestore` instead